# NSObject Delegate Methods are not being called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, nfc

I'm building a NFC reading app. I want all my NFC implementation to be inside a separate class called NFCReader, so I can call it every time the user taps the readNFC button in my MainVC. Here is my current MainVC code:

```
class MainVC: ViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var readNFCButton: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addTargetToReadNFCButton()
    }
    
    private func addTargetToReadNFCButton() {
        readNFCButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(readNFCButtonTouched), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func readNFCButtonTouched() {
        NFCReader().beginNFCReaderSession()
    }
    
}
```

Here is my NFCReader class code:

```
class NFCReader: NSObject {
    
    var session: NFCReaderSession?
    
    func beginNFCReaderSession() {
        session = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: true)
        session!.alertMessage = "Hold your device near your tag for scanning"
        session!.begin()
    }
    
}

extension NFCReader: NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate {
    
    func readerSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession) {
        print("readerSessionDidBecomeActive")
    }
    
    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
        print("didDetectTags")
    }
    
    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
}
```

The problem is that NFCReader's delegate functions are never being called. If I put the code from my NFCReader class into my MainVC class and call it directly, delegate functions are being called every time I scan my NFC tags. This code works:

```
class MainVC: ViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var readNFCButton: UIButton!
    
    var session: NFCReaderSession?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addTargetToReadNFCButton()
    }
    
    private func addTargetToReadNFCButton() {
        readNFCButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(readNFCButtonTouched), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func readNFCButtonTouched() {
        beginNFCReaderSession()
    }
    
    func beginNFCReaderSession() {
        session = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: true)
        session!.alertMessage = "Hold your device near your tag for scanning"
        session!.begin()
    }
    
}

extension MainVC: NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate {
    
    func readerSessionDidBecomeActive(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession) {
        print("readerSessionDidBecomeActive")
    }
    
    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
        print("didDetectTags")
    }
    
    func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    
}
```

Is there any way to make delegate functions work from my NFCReader class, not from MainVC? What's the mistake in my separate implementation?

Any help is appreciated!

EDITED:

I solved it by adding NFCReader property to main MainVC class:

```
  let nfcReader = NFCReader()
```

And calling it like this:

```
 @objc func readNFCButtonTouched() {
     nfcReader.beginNFCReaderSession()
 }
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Just adding to what has been already posted: What you need is a singleton to hold your reader session object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `NFCReader` is being initialized, and then almost immediately deinitialized because you didn’t store any references to it (which is necessary to keep the object alive).

You can confirm this by putting a breakpoint in the `deinit` of your `NFCReader` class

Comment: Thank you, you're right, it's deinitialized immediately, but I still can't understand how to store a reference to it correctly.

Comment: @MaryLitv21 In much the same way your alternatate code snippet stores `session`. You would make a stored property like `var nfcReader: NFCReader!` (it has to be mutable and optional because you set it outside of the VC initializer, a quirk of using VCs with storyboards), and then set `self.nfcReader = NFCReader()` in `viewDidLoad`.